# Does react-native-maps rerender the component when the this.props.region changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I have noticed when I move around the map, sometimes the map goes back a little (note! it **does not** go back to the previous **this.props.region** where the markers loaded).

I think, this is because **this.props.region** changes, therefore react rerenders the component since its state has changed **onRegionChangeComplete**. And, this only happens on **iOS!**

I am using

> Expo: 23.0.0
>
> react-native-maps: 0.17.1
>
> React Native 0.50
>
> React 16.0.0

Comment: I have the same issue. WOuld love to see a response tot his!